# Transform $\int \frac{x^2}{x - 2}$ to $ \int x +\frac{4}{x-2} + 2 $

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

I was trying to solve the following integral and I failed so I went to wolframalpha to see the step by step solution, but the following transformation is confusing me.

$\int \frac{x^2}{x - 2} = \int x +\frac{4}{x-2} + 2  $

I am unable to do the transformation by myself. Could you please explain the steps  to get from $\int \frac{x^2}{x - 2} $ to $\int x +\frac{4}{x-2} + 2  $ ? The step is labeled as a "long division", but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Do polynomial division. Take $x^2$ and divide by $x-2$. Either polynomial long division or synthetic division will give the answer.

Comment: More explicitly, $x^2 = (x-2)(x+2)+4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to do [polynomial division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/polydiv2.htm).

[image]

Therefore your answer would be 
$$x^2 \div (x-2)=x+2+\frac{4}{x-2}$$
**Note**: polynomial division uses the same principle as regular division when you have a remainder.

Answer (score 4):

First you want to reduce the rational function by polynomial division to get

$$
\frac{x^2}{x - 2} = \frac{x^2 - 2x + 2x}{x - 2} = x + \frac{2x}{x - 2}
$$

Then you want to perform partial fractions to reduce the resulting rational function to get

$$
\frac{2x}{x - 2} = \frac{ 2x - 4 + 4 }{ x - 2 } = 2 + \frac{4}{x - 2}
$$

Now I did some tricks to avoid longer calculations, but these steps are the steps you want to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the expression in exactly the same way you normally complete the square: $x^2 = (x^2 - 4x + 4) + 4x - 4 = (x-2)^2 + 4x-4$.

Then work with the linear terms in the same way: $4x - 4 = 4(x-2) + 8 - 4 = 4(x-2) + 4$.

Put it together to get $x^2 = (x-2)^2 + 4(x-2) + 4$.

Then you can throw in your denominator of $x-2$ and simplify:

$$\boxed{\frac{x^2}{x-2}} = \frac{(x-2)^2 + 4(x-2) + 4}{x-2} = (x-2 ) + 4 + \frac{4}{x-2} = \boxed{x + \frac{4}{x-2} + 2}$$

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easy and clear that:
$$\dfrac{x^2}{x-2}=\dfrac{x^2-4+4}{x-2}=\dfrac{(x-2)\cdot(x+2)}{x-2}+\dfrac{4}{x-2}=x+2+\dfrac{4}{x-2}$$ 
You can divide the polynomials or make the division by shape Horner, etc. Then, it is easy to calculate the integral.